# variable inverting op-amp Schmidt trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger

[image: inverting schmidt trigger]

I need to have variable high and low thresholds. Where do I put a variable resistor to get better results?(R1,R2 or R3)

Comment: With no R3 (or infinite R3) the threshold is set by the R1/R2 divider (Vth= Vref x R2/(R2+R1). | When R3 is present it will pull the threshold up when the output is up and down when the output is low. "Obviously"  lower value of R3 allows it to have more effect so will increase the hysteresis.

Comment: If you are interested in variable (selectable) hysteresis and keep it fixed once the selection is made, you might try this calculator:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/schmitt.html#c2
good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a variable resistor for R3 will give a variable amount of hysteresis.

Using a variable resistor for R1 or R2 will adjust the center point voltage (comparison voltage).

The actual switching points of the comparator will be at a voltage which is a combination of the center point voltage and the hysteresis amount.  When the output goes high the  hysteresis increases the comparison voltage, when the output goes low the hysteresis decreases the comparison voltage.

So you could say that R1 R2 adjusts the center point of the threshold, and R3 adjusts the high-low window width of the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

With no R3 (or infinite R3) the threshold is set by the R1/R2 divider (Vth= Vref x R2/(R2+R1).

When R3 is present it will pull the threshold up when the output is up and down when the output is low. "Obviously" lower value of R3 allows it to have more effect so will increase the hysteresis.

To have two independent thresholds you need two adjustments.
Use two variable pots in parallel in place of R3.
Place a diode in series with one, call it R3a, with cathode to output and a diode in series with the other, call it R3b with anode to output.

R3a will adjust the threshold when input is falling. 
R3B will adjust the threshold when input is rising.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have variable high and low thresholds.

If you need truly variable (and independent high and low threshold) use two comparators (no hysteresis required) and a flip-flop. Use one comparator output to set the flip-flop and the other to reset/clear that flip-flop.

A 555 uses the same sort of method: -

[image]

Maybe you could use a 555?

Comment: While that could be used to produce a solution, it is not one as it stands. He may well not be able to get from what you show to the final result. The external set / reset trigger points on a 555 are usually not fully independent  (2 x R charge, 1 x R discharge , with the discharge R also in the charge path).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm not offering a solution. I'm offering a couple of ideas and pointing out that the questioner may need more than he/she thinks.

Comment: Two pots and 2 diodes seem to give a fairly good result - same principle possible with 555 by somewhat less tidily.

Comment: @russell if you need independent thresholds that are supply independent hysteresis is a problem.

Comment: Aye. Silk purses and sows ears ... . I thought about adding a driven resistor with a clamp so that Vdrive_high was constant but it's not yet evident that it is worth spending that much effort of the query. Once / if we have OP response the Lily may perhaps be gilded.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the OP has long gone LOL!

Comment: ??? Asked ~= 2 days ago. No ???